# How to format BSC Scan API data in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, cryptocurrency, binance-smart-chain, bscscan

I am trying the **BSCscan** API today but I have a problem with the way prices are displayed.

https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001004&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

and it returns the following :

```
{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":"163794791233420992870477570"}
```

The result seems in an odd format...
In Google sheet, I use an ImportJSON formula and the result is the same.

What is that format ?
How can I do to get a correct response ?
Have I to convert it in some sort ?

Thanks for helping me !,
NiphtiAe

Comment: It seems it is displayed in weis... how to convert it ? will I get a balance in ETH ??

Comment: I found a way to convert it in ETH (divided by 10^18) and the in USD. But the results are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the format of the return is in WEIs, the smallest unit of the ETH, and the BNB.

I take the result, I times it by 10^18 and I have my balance in BNB. Then I can convert it in USD or else.

My next problem is that it only displays whats in the wallet, but not what is in farms, pools...

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue...From my understanding, the returned format is simply the token quantity held by that wallet address. However, it is in the form of a string and not float, so the correct result should be something like 163,794,791,233,420.992870477570.

To get this, first convert the string to float and divide it by 10^(N), where N is the number of decimals of the token. You can find it on https://bscscan.com/token/token-address or by calling "Get Token Info by ContractAddress" (API Pro endpoint)

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question, it's more of a comment/observation.